# Many date format conversion

Tags: c#

I need function to standardize date format.
I have string with date: 2015-12-01T00:00:00+00:00, 12/31/2018 01:00:00 etc.

I try this code:

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(this string date)
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
```

but I have error:

```
System.FormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime element.
  Source=mscorlib
  Ślad stosu:
   w System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
   w System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
   w InsuranceService.Common.ExtensionMethods.StringExtensionMethods.ToDateTime(String date) w \\Mac\Home\Desktop\StringExtensionMethods.cs:wiersz 10
   w AutoMapper.Internal.DelegateBasedResolver`2.Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
   w AutoMapper.NullReferenceExceptionSwallowingResolver.Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
   w AutoMapper.PropertyMap.<>c.<ResolveValue>b__44_0(ResolutionResult current, IValueResolver resolver)
   w System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate](IEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 func)
   w AutoMapper.PropertyMap.ResolveValue(ResolutionContext context)
   w AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.MapPropertyValue(ResolutionContext context, Object mappedObject, PropertyMap propertyMap)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Well.. you used the format `yyyy-MM-dd` on a string that has 16 over chars..ParseExact needs Exact...

Comment: When your input doesn´t **exactly** match the format, `ParseExact`will certainly fail, won´t it? So my question is: what else do you expect? Did you try using `Parse` instead?

Comment: could I ask for a code to fix this problem? I'm just learning c # and I do not get it all :( It's best to learn from examples

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings,

Comment: I need to get the date in the format: yyyy-MM-dd. I thought I could add something like this: date = date.Replace ("T00: 00: 00 + 00: 00", ""); and this will solve the problem with the zones. 10/12/2018 - this is December 12, 2018

Comment: Remember that a `DateTime` object can't be formatted, so if you need to use `yyyy-MM-dd` somewhere, you'll need to convert the `DateTime` object to a string (ideally as close to where you use it in this form as possible).

Comment: Ho there was "Many date format" like the title stated. I througt there was many date all with this format.. Hey read [ask] and [mcve], so next time you have all the possible inputs and expected output in your question. To avoid any  back and forth , I have this new format etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple formats and you know the format of all possible formats, you can `ParseExact` with all of them.

From your example possible formats

```
string format1 = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzz"; //2015-12-01T00:00:00+00:00"
string format2 = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"; //12/31/2018 01:00:00
string format3 = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"; //01.12.2015 00:00:00
```

possible inputs

```
string input1 = "2015-12-01T00:00:00+00:00";
string input2 = "12/31/2018 01:00:00";
string input3 = "01.12.2015 00:00:00";
```

parsing

```
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(input1, new[] { format1, format2, format3 }, 
                                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                      System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

so `ParseExact` will pick the first valid format and give you a result.

Comment: its not working. I have in result 01.12.2015 00:00:00

Comment: I'm testing: date =  "2015-12-01T00:00:00+00:00", and your's code: string format1 = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzz"; 
string format2 = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
string format3 = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"; 
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, new[] { format1, format2, format3 },
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None); - in result I have: {01.12.2015 01:00:00}